# How to fade in a specific CSS property

Tags: javascript, html, css, border, fadein

I want to fade in a border color from grey to red on an element on focus.

Getting the color to change immediately is easy, but I want it to fade in slowly.

**HTML**

```
<input class="timeBlock destination hours" 
    type="text" 
    name="desHours" 
    value="00" 
    maxlength="2">
```

**CSS**

```
input.timeBlock {
    height: 90px;
    width: 90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #444;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset; 
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

input.focus {
    border: 3px solid #cc0000;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("input").focus(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
       $(this).addClass('focus');
  });
});
```

Comment: apply transition in it .If u don't know about the transition effect google that since css3 has a property called transition which is what u need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use JavaScript to achieve this. The CSS3 `transition` property is very useful:

```
input {
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    transition:border 1s;
}
input:focus {
    border: 3px solid #cc0000;
}
```

[See working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbuk6/).

A little side note: bear in mind they've worked for a long time in Chrome and Firefox, but [IE<9 won't support them](http://caniuse.com/css-transitions). You'll still get a change in border color, but no transition.

Comment: Why the downvote? This literally does what you're asking for w/o JavaScript and using less markup?

Comment: Ian, I didn't give you the down vote. I don't even have the required reputation to vote yet! But, you're right -- the example does exactly what you said. If IE 9 won't support the transition, that's not a big deal. It at least just changes border color on focus. Any chance you know how to override Chromes default yellow focus border?

Comment: Hmm, I also explained it in much more detail than above! Could you at least put me at 0 for answering your question?

Comment: @lan Clark hey cool ,since  ur first post was incomplete i downvoted it,plz edit ur post so i can again upvote that .

Comment: @lan Clark u are just wasting time lying plz just edit nothing so that i can upvote ur post

Comment: Wasting time lying? I've never edited it until now, where I did add a couple of spaces - [look for yourself before you call me a liar](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18045767/revisions)

Comment: Ouch SO has gotten a little competitive - remember M, points cannot be redeemed for prizes :)

Comment: lol I know! I answer a question (correctly mind) and get downvoted because someone's trying to "win"...

Comment: Christ @ these comments. I didn't downvote but I assume it was downvoted because its CSS and OP wanted JS? (upvoted;)

Comment: @Neurofluxation haha - but then surely I wouldn't have gotten the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you could add a class to your html element with method `addClass` and fade it in.

HTML:

```
<input class="penguin"></input>
```

CSS:

```
.foobar {
    transition:border 1s;
    border: 38px solid #cc0000;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".penguin").focus(function() {
  $(this).fadeIn('slow', function(){
    $(this).addClass('foobar');
  });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ecj6Q/2/

When the input field receives focus the first time, it fades in as it adds the class foobar to any tags with class penguin.  The result is the border slowly increases in size from 0px to 38px over 1 second.

Comment: Transition is nothing more than the effect that lets an element gradually change from one state to another

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c6WcR/

Using Jquery UI

```
$("input").focus(function() {
$(this).animate({borderColor: "#ff0000" });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example of a CSS text effect fading in.

HTML:

```
<div id="penguin">Skipper</div>
```

CSS:

```
#penguin {
    height: 90px;
    width: 250px;
    font-size: 3.5em;
    color: blue;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.15) inset; 
}
#penguin:hover {
    text-shadow: green 0 0 5px;
    transition:text-shadow 1s;
}
```

Demo Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Gbuk6/4/

When you hover over the div, the text fades in and flares out.  When you stop hovering, it fades out back to where it was.